# Multiple different terrains type for landscape

Tags: materials, modifiers, displacement

I am trying to create a landscape with different type of terrains. Normally, what I would do is to create a big plan for a meadow which has dirt material/texture and grass particle. The meadow has modifier displacement to have hills/valleys effects. On a part of that meadow, I would like to make it look like sand (so no grass, no dirt but sand), or gravel (with gravel displacement modifier and textures), or some other types of terrains. As they are on the same landscape, all type of terrains (dirt, sand, gravel) must be align with hills and bumps that already on the plan. However I do not know how to proceed. One idea is I can create different plans for different type of terrains but then I do not know how to align the plans together to have a smooth landscape (hills and valleys) results.

PS This is a for a close-up view, that's why I'll need really high quality terrains (gravel, dirt), each with real geometry from bump maps in displacement modifier. So low-poly texture painting would not be desired. And it is for Cycles

Comment: It is unclear at what point of the process you are having trouble. Please add images that show what you have so far and if possible upload a file. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the resulting link into your question using the [edit] link (between share and close)

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Currently I have no image (will add if you really need it) because I think it's quite simple to explain in words. I have edited the question to have more explanations.

Comment: A solution maybe around vertex groups and vertex weights and using one or more displacement modifiers (vertex group slot). But for a 'close up' view, not sure at all that it will meet the result you want. Could you add an illustration of the final result (some image with similar effect)?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I am not used to vertex groups and vertex weights so it would take some time.